# ASP Checkbox trigger an event in Javascript whenever it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkbox1" />
```

Whenever I check or uncheck my asp checkbox, it needs to trigger an event in javascript but it seems like the .click function is not triggered. Is the .click event wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#checkbox1").click(function (e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            //do something
        }
        else {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: check if you are using master page then id `checkbox1` will not work, you have to give the element some class and in javascript use that class selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change

```
$("#checkbox1").click(function (e) {
```

into

```
$("#<%= checkbox1.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
```

asp.net renamed the ID's of Controls to ensure there are no duplicates. If you check the HTML source the could look something like this: `ContentPlaceHolder1_checkbox1`. That is why jQuery cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work for you.
For dynamically created `element` you have to use `event delegation`, if you want to select by an attribute you can use an `attribute equals selector`.

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name='member']", function () {
              alert("CheckBox Changed.");
              if (this.checked) {alert("CheckBox checked.");}
              else{alert("CheckBox not checked.");}
          });
```

OR

```
$(document).on("change", "$('#<%=checkbox1.ClientID%>')", function () {
              alert("CheckBox Changed.");
              if (this.checked) {alert("CheckBox checked.");}
              else{alert("CheckBox not checked.");}
          });
```

Here is the link , and go through this link 
[JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/2fepaf0y/)